# Describing quotient set under the equivalence relation $x \sim y$ iff $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$.

Tags: solution-verification, equivalence-relations

I don't have any trouble showing that for any function $f: X \to Y$, the relation $x \sim y$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$ is an equivalence relation, all properties of which follow from reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity of equality.

Now, I take $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \sin(x)$, so $x \sim y$ if and only if $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$. This is certainly an equivalence relation, so I need only describe the equivalence classes and quotient set. I'm not sure I've done so accurately. Here is my (updated, after some helpful comments) attempt.

> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We have $x \sim y$ if and only if $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$, so the equivalence class of $x$ is the fibre of $x$ over the sine map (and the quotient set is the set of all such fibres). In particular, we know that $\sin(x) = \sin(x + 2\pi k)$ ($k \in \mathbb{Z}$) and $\sin(x) = \sin(\pi - x)$, so $\sin(x) = \sin(\pi - x) = \sin(\pi - x + 2\pi k)$. We then have:
> \begin{align*}
> x \sim y & \iff \sin(x) = \sin(y) \\
> & \iff y = x + 2\pi k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ or } y = \pi - x + 2\pi k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \\
> & \iff y = x + 2k \pi, k \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ or } y = (2k + 1)\pi - x, k \in \mathbb{Z} \\
> & \iff y = 2k \pi + (-1)^{2k} x, k \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ or } y = (2k+1) \pi + (-1)^{2k+1} x \\
> & \iff y = n \pi + (-1)^n x, n \in \mathbb{Z}. 
> \end{align*}
> So
> $$
> [x] = \{y \in \mathbb{R} \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, \; y = n \pi + (-1)^n x\}. 
> $$

How does this updated attempt look? The only "description" of the quotient set that I know of, other than the set of all equivalence classes $[x]$ above, is the set of fibres of the sine map.

Comment: Note that $\sin(x)=\sin(y) \iff (x=y+2k\pi \text{ or } x=\pi-y + 2q\pi)$ ($k$ and $q$ integers). For example, $\sin(\pi/3)=\sin(2\pi/3)$ but there is no integer $k$ such that $\pi/3 = 2\pi/3 + 2k \pi$.

Comment: It's not true that $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$ iff $y = x + 2\pi k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Find the equivalence classes in $[0,2\pi)$ first.

Comment: @Taladris I'm afraid I haven't heard of the second identity. Does it have a name?

Comment: $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$. You can visualize this by using the unit circle or use the difference identity. And so by periodicity, $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x+2\pi k)$

Comment: The set can be described more simply as $ [x] = \{ n \pi + (-1)^n  \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ because each $n$ gives one $y$. Your current argument is insufficient to assure that there is no other $y$ satisfying $\sin x=\sin y$.  For one approach, odd $n$ correspond to the case $\cos x=-\cos y$ and even $n$ correspond to the case $\cos x=\cos y$.

Comment: @aerile My apologies, I just noticed the typo. Using your updated notation, I meant to say $[x] = \{n \pi + (-1)^n x \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Does this notation allow for other $y$? I'm a bit confused on why that could be the case since I believe every step in my above proof was reversible.

Comment: Your derivation is correct and complete. I also like your set notation, specifying first the domain y belongs to and then restricting it with a logical condition. If you want to be a bit more explicit in the first step, then you can use the well-known identity: sin(θ) - sin(φ) = 2 * sin((θ - φ) / 2) * cos((θ + φ) / 2), but this makes the derivation longer. Just another possibility, I like it the way it is, too.

Comment: @Cardinality Sorry, I also missed the typo. Well, your argument from the line $x \sim y \Leftrightarrow ...$ is completely reversible. My concern is about the argument before that. It only states $\sin x=\sin(x+2πk)$ and $\sin x=\sin(π-x+2πk)$, so I think it is insufficient to deduce $\sin(x)=\sin(y)⟺(y=x+2πk$ or $y=π−x+2πk)$.

Comment: @aerile  Yes, I think I see your point. I believe that final statement regarding the required relation between $x$ and $y$ is true, but I didn't know of a better way to prove it than to combine these two identities. Is there a way to make this more rigorous?

Comment: @Cardinality Of course the final statement is true. One may feel that you don't need to write something to prove it, especially if this problem is intended to ask the concept of quotient set, but others may feel otherwise and anyway it is better to be able to prove it when required. There are various approaches, as in other comments. Visualization by unit circle is very convincing, but less rigorous. Using the difference identity is rigorous and straightforward. My idea was dividing the case by whether $\cos x =\cos y$ as mentioned, which may require longer argument.

Comment: @Cardinality: $x$ and $\pi-x$ are supplementary angles, so it is sometimes called Supplementary angle identity (together with $cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)$).

Comment: @DavidP: $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$ follows more simply from the fact that the unit circle is symmetric about the $y$-axis.

Comment: @Taladris This identity makes sense to me now, thank you. Is there a way to deduce however that these are the only ways for which $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$? I think that is my only remaining problem for demonstrating the biconditional.

Comment: @Cardinality: that should be another (interesting) question. In short, $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$ means that the corresponding points on the unit circle have the same $y$-coordinates, so they are the same point ($y=x+2k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb Z$) or symmetric about the $y$-axis ($y=\pi-x+2q\pi$, $q\in\mathbb Z$).

Comment: @Taladris That was the first part of my comment.

Comment: @DavidP: I thought you meant $\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\sin(b)\cos(a)$, which a stronger result.

Comment: @Taladris yes thats why i mentioned that as a (rigorous as you put it) alternative, I mentioned the unit circle because it might have jogged their memory of trig and provide an "aha" moment